# Spring Integration File Writing Example

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-dsl

Is there any working example for file writing support of the Spring Integration DSL? I cannot find anything about DSL implementation.(e.g. a handle() step in the integration flow, etc.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#_configuring_with_the_java_dsl_9):

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileWritingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("fileWritingInput")
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "foo.txt")
                      .header("directory", new File(tmpDir.getRoot(), "fileWritingFlow")))
            .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(m -> m.getHeaders().get("directory")))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("fileWritingResultChannel"))
            .get();
}
```

The [File-Split-FTP](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp) may give you some insights too.